# Accordion Panels wont open (how do i keep div behind others)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im making a personal website here and i need a div in the background that goes from the top to the botton. (In this case its the one named 'sidebar' and is red.) When i added this it kinda broke the accordion panels i had. Im guessing its something with the z-index, or position relative. Or maybe i need to add a z-index to all for them to make them come to top. Not sure, any help would be appreciated.

CSS fo the sidebar div:

```
#sidebar{
height: 720px;
width: 270px;
background-color: red;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is a FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/dvr2pm6x/

Comment: jQuery? where's your jQuery in the jsFiddle demo? Also, why don't you include the relevant code right within your question!?

Answer (score 1):

You have `z-index: -1;` on `#sidebar`. That will put it behind `body` and any other element it might overlap that has either no `z-index` or a higher `z-index`, which makes `#sidebar` unclickable. Just to illustrate, you can set `position: relative; z-index: -2;` on `body` and then you can click `#sidebar`. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dvr2pm6x/2/).

Remove the negative `z-index` and `#sidebar` will be clickable. https://jsfiddle.net/dvr2pm6x/3/

Comment: Learnt something about z-index today. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make the sidebar position as absolute. here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dvr2pm6x/1/

```
#sidebar{
    height: 720px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```